# Pull Moredata from database SQLite, When scroll bottom in listview

Tags: android, listview

how to pull more data if listview in scroll botton.
This is my code:

```
DatabaseHandler database;
ListView mylist;

ArrayList<NewsItem> items;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category, container, false);

        mylist = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.categoryNewsItemGrid);

        mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // retrieve the NewsItem at the index of the click
                NewsItem item = (NewsItem) mylist.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                // view the item
                clickHandler.onItemClick(item.getId());
            }
        });


        mylist.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView list, int state) {
                if (state == OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                // check to see if all the visible items have images
                int firstVisible = list.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                int lastVisible = list.getLastVisiblePosition();
                for (int i = firstVisible; i <= lastVisible; i++) {
                    NewsItem item = (NewsItem) list.getAdapter().getItem(i);
                    // if this item doesn't have a thumbnail
                    if (item.getThumbnailBytes() == null) {
                        // load the thumbnail
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putInt(ResourceService.KEY_ITEM_ID,
                                item.getId());
                        service.sendMessageToService(
                                ResourceService.MSG_LOAD_THUMB, bundle);
                    }
                }
            }
            }

            public void onScroll(AbsListView list, int firstVisible,
                    int visibleItems, int totalItems) {
                if (visibleItems != 0
                        && ((firstVisible + visibleItems) >= (totalItems))) {

                    Log.d("MyLog", "count: "+totalItems);

                }
            }
        });
        displayCategory(getArguments().getString("category"));

        return view;
}

public void displayCategory(String categoryTitle) {

    items = new ArrayList<NewsItem>(Arrays.asList(database.getItems(
            categoryTitle, 10)));
    mylist.setAdapter(new ItemAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_news_item,
            items, 70, 70));
}
```

Function query to database in file DatabaseHandler.java

```
public NewsItem[] getItems(String category, int limit) {
    // ask the content provider for the items
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
            DatabaseProvider.CONTENT_URI_ITEMS_BY_CATEGORY, category);
    String[] projection = new String[] { DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ITEM_ID,
            DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ITEM_TITLE,
            DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ITEM_DESCRIPTION,
            DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ITEM_URL,
            DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ITEM_THUMBNAIL };
    String sortOrder = DatabaseHelper.RELATIONSHIP_TABLE + "."
            + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_RELATIONSHIP_PRIORITY + " ASC, "
            + DatabaseHelper.ITEM_TABLE + "."
            + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ITEM_PUBDATE + " DESC";
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null,
            sortOrder);

    // check the cursor isn't null
    if (cursor == null) {
        // bail here, returning an empty array
        return new NewsItem[0];
    }

    // load the column names
    int id = cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ITEM_ID);
    int title = cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ITEM_TITLE);
    int description = cursor
            .getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ITEM_DESCRIPTION);
    int url = cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ITEM_URL);
    int thumbnail = cursor
            .getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ITEM_THUMBNAIL);

    // load the items into an array
    ArrayList<NewsItem> items = new ArrayList<NewsItem>();

    while (cursor.moveToNext() && cursor.getPosition() < limit) {
        NewsItem item = new NewsItem(); // initialize a new item
        item.setId(cursor.getInt(id));
        item.setTitle(cursor.getString(title));
        item.setDescription(cursor.getString(description));
        item.setUrl(cursor.getString(url));
        item.setThumbnailBytes(cursor.getBlob(thumbnail));
        items.add(item); // add this item to the array
    }

    cursor.close();

    return items.toArray(new NewsItem[items.size()]);
}
```

If i see in logcat with Log.d("MyLog", "count: "+totalItems);
i get **count: 10**, because i set it to 10 when first show listview.

My question, how to load more data row in listview when i scroll in bottom, because in database i have until +30 row data. I have see tutorials in internet, but not success. Maybe in here, solved my problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to open your database and then in the onScroll() if you reach to end query the Database to get next 10 items and append to adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged() on adapter . So the first time your app opens you will pull, let's say 10 rows, and then after scroll you will query the database and pull more the next 10 rows. please check the below example code.

```
public class GrowingListViewActivity extends ListActivity implements OnScrollListener  {
Aleph0 adapter = new Aleph0();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setOnScrollListener(this);
}

public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisible, int visibleCount,
        int totalCount) {

    boolean loadMore = /* maybe add a padding */
    firstVisible + visibleCount >= totalCount;

    if (loadMore) {
        adapter.count += visibleCount; // or any other amount
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView v, int s) {
}

class Aleph0 extends BaseAdapter {

    int count = 40; /* starting amount */

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        return pos;
    }

    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        return pos;
    }

    public View getView(int pos, View v, ViewGroup p) {
        TextView view = new TextView(GrowingListViewActivity.this);
        view.setText("entry View : " + pos);
        return view;
    }
}
 }


  public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements
    OnScrollListener {
private final Context context;
private final ArrayList<String> values;

static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView text;
    public ImageView image;
}

public CustomArrayAdapter(Context arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
        ArrayList<String> arg3) {
    super(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
    this.context = arg0;
    this.values = arg3;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    int product_id = 0;
    View rowView = new View(context);
    try {

        ImageView wic_logo = new ImageView(context);
        TextView label = new TextView(context);

        String p = values.get(position);

        label.setText(p);

        wic_logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        Log.d("Custom Array Adapter", "at" + position);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Custom Array Adapter", "catch");
    }

    return rowView;
}

public void onScroll(AbsListView arg0, int firstVisibleItem,
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    Log.d("entered onScroll", " " + firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount
            + totalItemCount);
    if (((firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount) >= totalItemCount - 1)) {
        Log.d("entered if", " " + firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount
                + totalItemCount);
        // if we're at the bottom of the listview, load more data
        addData(totalItemCount, totalItemCount); // values.get(totalItemCount));
    }
}

private void addData(int totalItemCount, int productId) {

    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "last item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView arg0, int arg1) {

}

  }
```

i think this will help you.

Comment: Sorry, too long with my code to implement with your solution,

Answer (score 0):

You have to open your database and then on every scroll stated change query the Database and limit your result to the number you want! So the first time your app opens you will pull, let's say 10 rows, and then after scroll you will query the database and pull more the next 10 rows!!!

**Update**

Lets make it a little easier! Create an ArrayList with your type of data! and the make a private int limitCounter = 0;. After that get all your data from the database and insert it to the ArrayList. Then when you scroll you will change the value of the limitCounter and pull the appropriate data from it, so that you wont have to query the database every time.

Update #2

Try the following tutorial it will help you: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, yes i know this logic, but how to code for implement it

Comment: Check the tutorial i added!