# How to add button in footer below listview in layout with fragment

Tags: android, android-layout

How to add button in footer below listview in layout with fragment.
I have code as below:

In fragment java.

```
ListView listview;
Button button;


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category, container, false);
        View footerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_category, null);
        listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.categoryNewsItemGrid);
        listview.addFooterView(footerView);

    loadmore = (Button) footerView.findViewById(R.id.loadMore);
    loadmore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Log.d("Mylog","Button can click");
        }
    });

        return view;
}
```

/res/layout/category.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/categoryNewsItemGrid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#C5C5C5"
        android:dividerHeight="2px" />

</LinearLayout>
```

/res/layout/footer_category.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/footerCategory"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loadMore"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="Load More" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And i get error(Force Close), if i see in logcat, i get message error Android Runtime in line 74, line 74 is:

```
View footerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_category, null);
```

My question, i want to add button in footer, below listview. like as [this screenshot](http://www.androidhive.info/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/output_listview_loadmore_button.png).
thanks.

Comment: What is wrong with your current code?

Comment: Force Close, if i remove addFooterview and loadmore in java code it fine.

Comment: Please post the LogCat errors.

Comment: Error with tag Android Runtime in createView line 74, line 74 is View footerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_category, null);

Comment: i have edit in my question post with error in logcat.

Comment: Hmm, try `View footerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_category, container, false);`. But that is just a guess, if it doesn't work please cut & paste all of the LogCat errors and post them in your question.

Comment: Hi sam my problem is solved with answer vmironov, thanks sam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed `layout_height` in your `/res/layout/footer_category.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/footerCategory"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loadMore"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Load More" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi thanks, now button show, but if scroll to bottom i get foce close, i see in logcat error is OnScrollStateChage.

Comment: If you want to see code scrollstatechange you can look in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216589/pull-moredata-from-database-sqlite-when-scroll-bottom-in-listview, it is my problem related with this code, in the post previous i want load more data when listview in scroll bottom, but now i want to load data with button load more, and then there the post i not get answered solution. Thanks

Comment: Hi vmironov. Problem is solved with adding button in footer, can you help me again with the post, implement with button more, like this link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/ . Thanks