# Add button at end Listview android

Tags: java, android

so , i have a Listview activity , that is populated by values from a SQLITE database.

how can i put a button fixed at top or bottom ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/coligada"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editar"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/editar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Quantidadesxsx"
    android:onClick="editar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/coligada"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/coligada" />







 </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my ProductAdapter that have custom layout  where have the items and a apdater that populate my listview with values from Sqlite database.

```
package br.exemplosqlite;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class ProdutosAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private List<Produtos> list;

public ProdutosAdapter(Context context, List<Produtos> list){
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.get(arg0).getId();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    final int auxPosition = position;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.produtos, null);

    TextView tv = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.coligada);
    tv.setText(list.get(position).getItem());


    Button editarBt = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.editar);
    editarBt.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewUserActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("item", list.get(auxPosition).getItem());
               intent.putExtra("quantidaderm",list.get(auxPosition).getQuantidaderm());
            intent.putExtra("id", list.get(auxPosition).getId());

            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    // *********** BOTÃO DE EXCLUIR ***************** //
    //Button deletarBt = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.deletar);
    //deletarBt.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
    //  @Override
    //  public void onClick(View arg0) {
    //      BD bd = new BD(context);
    //      bd.deletar(list.get(auxPosition));
    //
    //      layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    //  }
    //}
    ///);

    return layout;
}

}
```

Comment: also show your layout where you created listview

Comment: show your full listview layout here...

Comment: the Layout xml above if full code.

Ajay , could u make a example with my code ?

Comment: Can you give the design png how it should looks like?

Comment: where you want to fix the button inside listview or outside listview

Comment: is like this , http://imgur.com/eyVLyXL . i wanna put a botton at bottom or top

Comment: @ThiagoEmanoel use header or footer option in listview

Comment: @ThiagoEmanoel try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14221182/1765530

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following xml at the bottom of `ListView` and `centerHorizontal`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Your Button"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: are you setting this layout file for `ListView Item layout` or your MainActivity layout?

Comment: MainActivity , the ProductsAdapter

Comment: that's the problem. This layout is supposed to be used for every item so you should not used the above layout in this Adapter. The layout i shared is supposed to be used in MainActivity and then for list item, create the separate layout file which will contain the view to be used in every row.

Comment: You should set my layout which i shared in `MainActivity` and then the layout file you shared `R.layout.produtos`, keep the file as it is. Can you show your MainActivity code and its xml?

Answer (score 0):

Current layout is for listview items.

Remove Button from this layout file and paste it in layout file where you have defined ListView.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

    <ListView
       .....
    </ListView>
    <Button>
    </Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

in one layout and

```
<TextView>

</TextView>
```

in another layout

Comment: sorry , i dont undestood . can u make a example ?

Comment: To make it simple. You should have 2 layout xml files. 1 should have listview and button and other should have  textview.

Comment: Sanky , how can call two Layouts ?

Comment: layout with listview you have to use in your main activity in setContentView. Other layout file set when you create Adapter object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104959/discussion-between-sanky-jain-and-thiago-emanoel).

Comment: Okay , i 'm so newbie at Java , but i'll try undestand this.

Answer (score 0):

In button add this line of code

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/editar"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Quantidadesxsx"
android:onClick="editar"
android:layout_below="@+id/coligada"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your text here"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: that " Your text here " is now displaying in each row of my listview.

Comment: It looks like you are using this XML as your row's layout. This XML is the fragment XML, and will display the textview at the bottom of the screen, anchored there. If you wanted the button at the top instead, just swap the listview and textview order in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.05"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/coligada"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editar"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Large Text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/editar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/coligada"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/coligada"
            android:onClick="editar"
            android:text="Quantidadesxsx" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: application crashed when i change to this xml code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    <Button
 android:id="@+id/btn"
layout_width="wrap_content"
layout_height="wrap_content"
android:alignParentTop="true"
/>

<ListView
layout_width="wrap_content"
layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/btn"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:layout_weight="1"` with `LinearLayout`.

**Example.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/editar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Quantidadesxsx"
    android:onClick="editar"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i cannot change to <Listview , because i 'm using a <Textview , how can i convert to <ListView ?

Comment: Post here sketch of your design.

Comment: What you want? In your question you said that you want button at bottom of listview. What is your main problem? Please post sketch image of your layout.

Comment: http://imgur.com/eyVLyXL here is my Layout . i want put a buttom at top or bottom fixed.

Comment: And if you want to text just in 1 line then add this line `"android:singleLine="true"` in `TextView`.

Comment: hey Chirag , the application crashed, after change.

Comment: Post your logcat here so I can help you.